# popping activity stack and savedActivityState == null

Tags: android, android-activity

I have following Activity flow scenario, this is like wizard:
A->B->C->D

First activity `A` opens, user does something and I do save state in `onSaveInstanceState`

Then user goes to activity `B`, then `C`, then `D` and I can click `back` at any time, come back to activity `A` and state correctly restores, `savedActivityState` is there.

Problem I have is, when user get's to `D` and "confirms" everything - I need to take them back to `A` showing results of their work. I use this code to return to `A` and pop whole stack:

```
// Return to main screen and pop stack
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanSendActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I expected this to act different (have `savedActivityState`), but it looks like whole activity stack get's cleared and this activity `A` created as new instance.

How do I come back to my "original" activity `A` and kill `B,C,D` ?

Answer (score 0):

> ...but it looks like whole activity stack get's cleared and this activity A created as new instance.

You are right, that is exactly what is happening. The whole stack is cleared and there is a new instance of the A activity, which is why you don't have the saved instance. When you create a new Intent, you are creating a new Activity essentially.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) regarding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

This means that while it's not a new Activity, it is a new intent, with a new data structure passed into the Activity, which will erase the `savedInstanceState`

To get the data, I would pass the data between the activities. How you do this will depend on the data, but you can use `Parcelable`, `Bundle`, and `Extras`.

Comment: Yes, but if I do this - it will be very smelly code. Activity is there, I can click back 3 times to get to it and it will restore properly. Can't believe there is no way to do that programmatically?

Comment: Passing the data isn't "smelly code". It's good programming practice. Using data structures to store the data, and save it is what you are supposed to do. This will give you more flexibility as your app grows IMO.

Comment: In this case it is. Saving activity state perfectly fine. I need to save some field values. Now I need to create some global object? Or create structure and pass through B/C/D and back into new instance of A? This is definitely not a "nice" solution

Comment: First off, I wouldn't create a global object. That is bad programming. What I said was to pass the data between the activities. Depending on the data, you can simply use `Bundle`. It's up to you to determine what the best method is. If it's simple data, that just put some extra's in when you create a new intent.

Comment: I'll also add that using the `onSaveInstanceState()` method for what you are trying to do is not what it's intended for. That method is there to keep the current data if the activity gets destroyed and needs to resume, when something like an orientation change happens. It's not designed to be used to store data when moving between activities.